# Most efficient way to update/create records in rails with slightly different records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, syntax

so I am uploading distribution lists to an app I just started which have a variety of item information. So, for example I have excel sheets, openoffice sheets, and csv files that will have rows containing data such as:

```
[(itemsource: "Moen", itemnumber: "S7170SRS", description: "Spot Resist Single Mount Kitchen Faucet", handles: "1")]

[(itemsource: "Delta", itemnumber: "DL02GD", description: "Faucet Cartridge", faucetstyle: "vessel")]
```

Let's assume I convert them all to csv. Then I can use:

```
file = File.open(file)
csv = CSV.parse(file, headers: true)
csv.each do |row|
  Product.create!(row.to_hash.compact)
```

Which is called on my itemcontroller:

```
def import

  file = params[:file]
  return redirect_to items_path, notice: "No file selected." if file == nil
  return redirect_to items_path, notice: "Import files must be of CSV format." unless file.content_type == "text/csv"
  csvimport.new.call(file)

  return redirect_to products_path, notice: "File has been successfully uploaded!"
end
```

Now, the issue I have is that any items that are already in my system will be ignored since the itemnumber is already taken. I need to devise a way to update when in the system, and create when it is new.

The one wrinkle I see is since the columns are not identical between the arrays/rows that I cannot just use
`item.find_or_create_by!(row.to_hash.compact)`

I was thinking of using conditionals with logic such as:

```
if itemnumber == row("itemnumber") && itemsource == row("itemsource") then use item.find_or_create_by!(row.to_hash.compact)

else use item.create!(row.to_hash.compact)
```

But this seems less efficient than using a single method that has already been created.

Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: In general processing this one row at a time and doing N+1 number of read and insert/update queries isn't going to be very efficient anyways so I would not worry so much about exactly what methods you're using. That's kind of focusing on the wrong problem.

Comment: If you want to create or update a record you instead want to call `find_or_initialize_by(...)` and then call `update/update!` which will save the record. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-or-initialize-by

Comment: The `find_or_create_by` method selects the record if it is present or inserts it if not already. This already handles the `else` part you are handling with the `create` method, so it is unnecessary. You could simply do- `item.find_or_create_by!(row.to_hash.compact)`